# How do I join an array of keys with an array of values to a dictionary without a loop?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of keys and values from which I want to create a dictionary:

```
var keys = new string[] { "Key1", "Key2" };
var values = new string[] { "Bob", "Tim" };
```

The imperative way would be this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for(int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++) {
  dictionary.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```

How would I do this without loops? Probably with Linq? I've looked at Array.Join, but can't figure out how to make it work for me in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) (to combine keys and values into single sequence) and [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548657%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (to convert that sequence to dictionary).

Sample:

```
var result = keys.Zip(values, (k,v) => new {k,v})
  .ToDictionary(p => p.k, p => p.v);
```

Answer (score 6):

There's an awesome `ToDictionary` extension method.
The `Range` method is simply to loop over the indices, and it assumes that both arrays are not null and of the same length.

```
var dictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, keys.Length)
                     .ToDictionary(i => keys[i], i => values[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2 loops anyway:

```
var dic = keys.Select((k, i) => new { Key = key, Value = values[i] })
              .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

assuming that `keys` and `values` are symmetric.